# Angular Bootstrap uibModal not resolve attributs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Roles** property not resolve in AngularJS bootstrap uiModel.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: 100,
  resolve: {
    roles: function () {
         return $scope.roles;
    }
  }
});
```

See ngRepeat code which read the value of **Roles** and making dom elements.

```html
 <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in roles">
           <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item.name }}</a>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

**Also error shows on console** : Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: itemsProvider <- items <- ModalInstanceCtrl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some sort of research I found that Angular only resolve **items** property in uiModel, so when user want to get values from other attributes then angular not respond properly.

Find the updated code

```js
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: 100,
  resolve: {
  items: function () {
   return $scope.userInfo;
 }
  }
});
```

```html
 <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items.role">
        <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item.name }}</a>
        </li>
 </ul>
```

**Explaination** : **$scope.userInfo** is the JSON object which contains the role key and role contains the list of role

Comment: Tip: Use controllerAs Syntax in your Modal with: controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl as myCtrl' then you can Access your variables with ' ng-repeat="item in myCtrl.items.role"'

Comment: your tip not working out for me. controller not wrap into some another alias